# Cassandra HealthCheck in Asp.net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, cassandra, health-check

I'm using asp.net core [health-check](https://github.com/Xabaril/AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks) but I couldn't find any provider for the Cassandra database.

Is there any specific reason that they didn't implement it? or Can I easily use a simple query to check the connection like below?

`SELECT now() FROM system.local;`

In Addition, should I check the status of each node in the cluster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I easily use a simple query to check the connection like below?

Yes.  SELECTing anything from `system.local` should be a good indication that the cluster is up and accepting connections.

> In Addition, should I check the status of each node in the cluster?

No, because the driver uses individual node IPs only as a way to find the cluster.  The node which coordinates the request isn't something that can be programmatically determined.